# How to get total physical memory (ram) information in GB by WMI query?

Tags: windows, wmi, wmic, wql

I know how to get total physical memory from `Win32_ComputerSystem` class. but that comes in bytes or kb. I want this information in MB or GB. In WMI (wql) query. wmic also work. thanks in advance.

Comment: So, why don't you convert it yourself? (if you're coding, in code, otherwise, paste it to Excel with a formula or something like that...)

Comment: In case you might be looking for some other way to get the RAM size: http://www.commonfixes.com/2014/12/get-systems-physical-ram-using-csharp.html

Answer (score 8):

you can convert `TotalPhysicalMemory` of [Win32_ComputerSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Try this :

```
using System;
using System.Management;
namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                    "SELECT TotalPhysicalMemory FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                { 
                    double dblMemory;
                    if(double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(queryObj["TotalPhysicalMemory"]),out dblMemory))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TotalPhysicalMemory is: {0} MB", Convert.ToInt32(dblMemory/(1024*1024)));
                        Console.WriteLine("TotalPhysicalMemory is: {0} GB", Convert.ToInt32(dblMemory /(1024*1024*1024)));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You must convert the value of the property manually. Also is better use [Win32_PhysicalMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394347%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope Scope;
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", "."), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT Capacity FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);
                UInt64 Capacity = 0;
                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Capacity+= (UInt64) WmiObject["Capacity"];
                }
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Physical Memory {0} gb", Capacity / (1024 * 1024 * 1024))); 
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Physical Memory {0} mb", Capacity / (1024 * 1024)));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to make mention that I used the Win32_PhysicalMemory Capacity property until I met inconsistent results on Windows Server 2012. Now I use both properties (Win32_ComputerSystem:TotalPhysicalMemory and Win32_PhysicalMemory:Capacity) and choose the larger of the two.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that lands here now (this post is 10 years old)

**Get-WmiObject** is deprecated in **PowerShell 3.0** and above. ( Source : https://ss64.com/ps/get-wmiobject.html)

**Get-WmiObject** is being replaced with **Get-CimInstance**, which is so much better in many ways!

If you are still wanting to do this, please consider using the following -

## Code

```
$MemoryUncleaned = (Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).sum /1gb
$Memory = $MemoryUncleaned.ToString() + "GB"
$Memory
```

## Output

```
64GB
```