# Windows 7 - Get RAM details using powershell script

Tags: powershell

Is there any direct/simple command to get the RAM information through PS script, for example 4GB.

For eg. to retrieve OS Name I am using this command:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get total physical memory size using PowerShell without WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681234/how-do-i-get-total-physical-memory-size-using-powershell-without-wmi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, using the WMI objects.

The quick answer is:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).totalphysicalmemory / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

It is based on this answer:

[How to get total physical memory (ram) information in GB by WMI query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041249/how-to-get-total-physical-memory-ram-information-in-gb-by-wmi-query)

You should consider switching to CIM.

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).totalphysicalmemory / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Read more about CIM vs. WMI here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2016/02/08/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has said that CIM is the future.

```
((Get-CimInstance CIM_PhysicalMemory).Capacity | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
```